# quote_from_bytes() expected bytes error when data is in bytes format when uploading to blob storage in Python3

Tags: azure-blob-storage, python-3.8

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong with trying to upload an image to blob storage? Below is my code.

```
print(type(img['image'])) #Output is <class 'bytes'>

connection_string = get_blob_connection_string()
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="images", blob=img['id'])

exists = blob_client.exists()
if (exists == False):
    result = blob_client.upload_blob(img['image'], blob_type="blockblob")
    print(result)
```

When inserting the blob, it throws the error

> quote_from_bytes() expected bytes

This error makes no sense, I gave it bytes. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, I have received the same issue. You are receiving this error because of incompatible type of the file (i.e., file format).

> [image]

After changing the below line to the correct format I could able to achieve your requirement.

```py
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="images", blob=img['id'])
```

Below is the correct format

```
blob_client=blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container='container', blob='<LOCAL FILE PATH>');
```

Below is the complete code that worked for me

```
from  azure.storage.blob  import  BlobServiceClient
from  PIL  import  Image

connection_string = "<CONNECTION STRING>"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
blob_client=blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container='container', blob='<LOCALPATH>');

with  open(file='<PATH IN YOUR STORAGE ACCOUNT WITH FILE NAME>', mode="rb") as  data:

blob_client.upload_blob(data)
```

**RESULTS:**

[image]

Comment: In your example, you have the file locally on disk. Is it not possible to do this with a byte array already in memory? In my situation, I am reading the image directly from an online source, so it never ends up as a file on the disk. I suppose I could write it to a temp file and delete it, but that seems like the wrong way of doing things.

Comment: It looks like things will work if it is given a path, regardless of the path actually exists on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause for this error is to provide [`BlobServiceClient.get_blob_client`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobserviceclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-blobserviceclient-get-blob-client) with a [`Path` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) as blob name (`blob` parameter). In this case, you must do the cast to string yourself:

```py
file_path = Path("my_path")
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="my_container", blob=str(file_path))
```

The same error occurs for [`ContainerClient.get_blob_client`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-containerclient-get-blob-client), [`ContainerClient.upload_blob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-containerclient-upload-blob) and probably other related methods.